# Inheriting IEnumerable<string> cause error CS0738

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, ienumerable

```
public class PatchInfo : IEnumerable<string>
{
    ...
    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        LinkedList<string> list = new LinkedList<string>();
        ...
        return list;
    }
}
```

name of interface is "IEnumerable" so i guess that return type "IEnumerator" may be corrected.

but it cause compile error

> CS0738 : ... does not implement interface member... because it does
>   not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'.

what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEnumarable< T> inherits [IEnumarable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx). So you need to implement `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` method also.

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

Also, your code won't compile, because `GetEnumerator` method should return `IEnumerator` instead of 
`IEnumarable`. Use GetEnumarator method to get `IEnumerator`.

```
public class TestEnumarable : IEnumerable<string>
{
    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
       LinkedList<string> a = new LinkedList<string>();

       return a.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: He'll still get an error as `list` is a `LinkedList<string>` and not a `IEnumerator<string>`

Comment: that code cause error CS0305:Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>' requires 1 type arguments...

Comment: @user3244483 on which line?

Comment: @Valentin IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() <- that line

Comment: @user3244483 add `using System.Collections;`